# aws-ssm launch my script file located in users home directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I currently have an ec2 instance named and tagged "test-dev" and inside it at I have a `test_batch.sh` and `hello_world.sh`  that I already prepared in the home dir of my user.

test_batch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "run hello world"
./hello_world.sh
```

hello_world.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello world"
```

According to the documentation I can run the test_batch.sh via the following command.

```
aws ssm send-command \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --targets Key=tag:Name,Values=test-dev \
    --parameters '{"commands":["cd ~/","bash test_batch.sh"]}' \
    --output text
```

it says that it can't find the referenced file hello_world.sh so I assume the test_batch.sh is called properly.

Comment: Can you add the output found in /var/log/amazon/ssm/ also can you check the file permissions as the user which runs the SSM script is a different user.

Comment: hello, I figured out yesterday that ssm runs as root? and my test requires me to use the ssm-user because I have my configs in /etc/bashrc where it wouldn't load if I run the batch with ssm.